# How to make a JButton unclickable after clicking on it?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Here's my code :

```
for(int row = 0; row < 10; row++)
{
    for(int col = 0; col < 10; col++)
    {
            button = new JButton();

            panel_1.add(button);
     }
 }

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //If Button is clicked, make the button unclickable
            if(button == (JButton)e.getSource())
            {
                button.setEnabled(false);

            }
        }

    });
```

I want to make any JButton I click from this 10 x 10 grid button layout unclickable; however, this method only makes no other that the right button unclickable, What's wrong? I have put the ActionListener outside the for-Loop that is responsible for making the buttons. I don't know what's going on.

Here's what it looks like :

[image]

Edit: bsd code works. Add ActionListener before adding the buttons or something along those lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only add the ActionListener to the last button created.

You need to add the ActionListener to every button created inside the loop.

So the code should be something like:

```
ActionListener al = new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
         JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
         button.setEnabled( false );
    }
};

for(int row = 0; row < 10; row++)
{
    for(int col = 0; col < 10; col++)
    {
            button = new JButton();
            button.addActionListener( al );
            panel_1.add(button);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to disable all buttons in your panel. The button action listener should be inside the for loop.

```
button = new JButton();
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        //If Button is clicked, make the button unclickable
        if(button == (JButton)e.getSource())
        {
            button.setEnabled(false);

        }
    }

});
```

Comment: No need to create a separate ActionListener for each button. The same ActionListener can be shared by all buttons.

Comment: This works thank you. Now I'm going to go and cry about other problems. Thank you.

Comment: @Anonymous Please accept the answer if you think it helped

Comment: @camickr you are right for this use case. Looking at the image, I feel that more functionality might be added to action listener for a group of buttons and all buttons need not react in the same way.

Comment: @Anonymous, I gave you the better solution. That should be the "accepted" answer.  Way waste resources creating 10 ActionListeners that do the same thing? What if you next application has 100 buttons? It is common to write generic listeners so they can be reused.

Comment: @bsd, Your suggestion was to add the ActionListener in the loop. Therefore the ActionListener is identical for all the buttons. Therefore there is no need to create 10 listener. Not only that there is no need for the if condition. You know automatically the source of the button is the button to change.